# Method ignores exceptional return value : FindBugs

Tags: java, findbugs

Why the heading error in the findbugs for the following code.

```
 boolean isCreated =  folder.mkdirs();

    if (!isCreated) {
        throw new IOException("Folder already exists..!!!");
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not coming from one of the other method calls on the folder object (presumably being a java.io.File instance).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Finds Bug Description.](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_BAD_PRACTICE)

> **Method ignores exceptional return value**
>
> Method returns a value that is not checked. The return value
>   should be checked since it can indicate an unusual or unexpected
>   function execution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're not checking for the [SecurityException that mkdirs can throw](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).

Comment: This is plain wrong. Read the Bug Description, it has nothing to do with catching SecurityException.