# Findbugs "Method ignores exceptional return value" java.io.File.mkdirs()

Tags: java, findbugs, mkdirs

I have the following code in my app:

```
final File f = new File(path);

try {
    boolean folderCreated = f.mkdirs();

    // if dir wasn't created this time, and doesn't exist
    if (!folderCreated && !f.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to create path");
    }
} catch (SecurityException e) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to create path");
}
```

When I run findbugs (in Android Studio), it reports `Bad Practice` `Bad use of return value from method` `Method ignores exceptional return value of java.io.File.mkdirs()`

Javadoc states that `java.io.File.mkdirs()` returns true if the directory was created, or false on failure OR if the directory already existed, hence the `!f.exists()` check.

I don't want to ignore findbugs messages - not even warnings, but I don't see how I can resolve this as the return value is clearly being checked.

Note, I added the `try{...}catch (SecurityException){...}` as a suggestion from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23631948/1423896, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: FindBugs 3.0.1 does not report any warnings on this code (because you actually check the `mkdirs` return value). Are you using the latest version? In general sometimes you should ignore FindBugs warnings. FindBugs can produce warnings which actually don't cause any problems in your code.

Comment: Android Studio (IntelliJ build 141.2178183) is reporting `Findbugs 3.0.1`, `FindBugs-IDEA 0.9.997`. findbugs was installed from Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the reason is that you invoke method of `f` instance even if `folderCreated` is false. Instead, you can invoke it before you invoke `f.mkdirs()`.

```
boolean folderExisted = f.exists() || f.mkdirs();
if (!folderExisted) {
    throw new IOException("Unable to create path");
}
```

refs: [CheckReturnAnnotationDatabase.java](https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-2.0.2/blob/e8ebba0e775bed94940ac8a581ccc0a4fbb23db7/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/ba/CheckReturnAnnotationDatabase.java)

Comment: It's very strange... I tried what you suggested, but the warning was still present. I rolled back to what I had before, and the message disappeared. I have cleaned/rebuilt/redeployed the project several times between each test, but the findbugs plugin reports inconsistent results.

Comment: @Tiksi, probably some bug in Intellij FindBugs plugin (I don't think it's the problem in FindBugs itself). If you can reproduce such behavior, consider reporting a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is relevant but it's a good idea to pass the caught exception to the created exception like this (on the last lines):

```
try {
    boolean folderCreated = f.mkdirs();

    // if dir wasn't created this time, and doesn't exist
    if (!folderCreated && !f.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to create path");
    }
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    throw new IOException("Unable to create path", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` condition to create a directory. That way you can eliminate findbug error. This works:

```
if (f.mkdir()) {
    System.out.println("directory " + f+ " created");
}
```